# Dart pub get generates link to packages in each folder and subfolders

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I try to avoid Dart to generate symbolic links (to `packages`) in each folder/sub-folder. For example, in `pubspec.yaml` I add `polymer` package and run `pub get`. After that I got:

[image]

Now each folder has `packages` symbolic link! As I understand it's because to ensure that we can use `package:..` statement in any Dart file in any subdirectory.

I've already read the following topic ([Why is dart pub suddenly trying to install packages in my css folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262638/why-is-dart-pub-suddenly-trying-to-install-packages-in-my-css-folder)), but it was created 2 years ago. Maybe something new here? How can I specify folders to exclude generating links by `pub`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These symlinks are necessary for many tools. You can use the experimental command line option `--no-package-symlinks` for `pub get`/`pub upgrade` to disable symlink creation. I tried this a while ago but the DartEditor debugger stopped working (see http://dartbug.com/21749).

There are plans to get rid of symlinks entirely. A [proposal](https://github.com/lrhn/dep-pkgspec/blob/master/DEP-pkgspec.md) exists and I assume it will be implemented within a few months (no promises).

**Update**
No `packages` directory and no symlinks might become default with Dart 1.13.